# Python + Django (total price and items are not changing!)

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I have this in cart.html : [Cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xgoc.png)

when I do the changes that I will show below the total price that's in the end with green plus is changed but the total price and items that are up are not showing at all after the changes I make !

so I do this :

in class OrderItem I add :

```
@property
def get_total(self):
    total = self.product.price * self quantity
    return total
```

then I go to my template   ----->   cart.html and I change the static total price of $40

to this :   `<div style="flex:1">${{item.get_total}}</div>`

and everything is alright with those changes but then I do changes as below

in class Order I add :

```
@property
def get_cart_total(self):
    orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
    return total

@property
def get_cart_items(self):
    orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
    total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
    return total
```

then I go to views.py and do this change :

from context = {'items':items}  ---->  context = {'items':items, 'order':order}

then do those changes in cart.html :

```
<th><h5>Items: <strong>3</strong></h5></th>  ------>  <th><h5>Items: <strong>{{order.get_cart_items}}</strong></h5></th>

<th><h5>Total: <strong>$43</strong></h5></th> ----->  <th><h5>Total: <strong>${{order.get_cart_total}}</strong></h5></th>
```

So from changes that I do from class Order and below nothing changes on runserver !

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcjAM.png)

[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dicAj.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as images, add it as text into the question.

Comment: Why can't you add them to the question? If you don't, it's much less likely someone will answer.

Comment: there's too much code and stackoverflow doesn't let me !

Comment: In that case an image won't help either. You should reduce the problem to a minimal failing example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: hey bro, I'm here to get help to solve my problem and not to argue what should I write in my question. thank you

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you updated the values or did you do them manually in the DB?

Comment: @Starbody what values ?

Comment: The value of `order.get_cart_items`

Comment: @Starbody no I have set them back as they were!

Comment: That is not what I meant, you know normally you would have a view where you update the values that's what I want to see

Comment: u have views.py in the end of the question together with models.py !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

it was because of namespaces before get !

thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code in the future in `code blocks` and not as screenshots.

The issue you are having is that your context of the `cart` view does not contain a `order` object.

Comment: I can't post views.py or models.py in code locks, it shows some errors ! thanks for issue suggestion, will look for that !